# How to get all items from timestamp as partition key in dynamodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table of temperature in dynamodb, I have set the timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) as Partition Key. I am using NodeJs for this program.

Here's one of the data

```
value: { N: '49.5' },
location: { S: '1' },
timestamp: { S: '2020-06-09 01:04:20' }
```

Now I want to get all items from a time range, such as from 9am to 11am on the same day, I tried the `query` function but all my timestamps are unique, now I am testing it with the `scan` function.
However, is there a better approach for this situation? Would change the `date` as Partition Key and `time` to Sort Key be better?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If that is the common query, you will want to have the timestamp be the sort key, not the partition key. You could have it in the partition key as well if your access patterns support that, but with it in the sort key, you can do a "begins_with" as a query operator and get what you are looking for. "Get all items from 9 June 2020 in the 13 hour." That will be about the cheapest way performance and cost wise. If you do this with a scan, it will likely be way too expensive over the long haul and you will be unhappy.

Your other option is to make a GSI with that attribute as the sort key. You will have to weigh the cost of maintaining a GSI with the cost of data duplication in the base table with the other method above. More than likely, I would probably choose the data duplication, but I do not know your workloads at all.

Comment: Hi @Kirk This is a University project, with 3 days worth data, logging in every 10 minutes. I wanted it to be cost-free if possible.

Comment: Got it. Then stick with QUERY and not SCAN, then stay inside of the DynamoDB free tier allocations and you should be good. https://go.aws/2v1eU2j